# Force immediate execution of IEnumerable query using Linq2Sql context

Tags: c#, performance, linq-to-sql, ienumerable

I've read a considerable amount of posts regarding the "possible multiple enumeration" issue. I think I understand the concepts of deferred vs. immediate execution, as well as the implications of returning interfaces vs. concrete types.

So given the data access layer method below and the test code, I am trying to force immediate execution of the query. `ToList()` works in the data access layer method, but not in the Main method (probably because `ToList()` is called after the context is disposed). Casting `as ReadOnlyCollection<Item>` (or `IReadOnlyCollection`) also do not work.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = GetItems(i => i.SupiCode.Contains("TestCode")).ToList(); // ObjectDisposedException (context)
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Item> GetItems(Func<Item, bool> filter)
    {
        using (var ctx = new RRPClassesDataContext())
        {
            return ctx.Item.Where(filter); //.ToList(); <-- this works
        }
    }
```

My objectives are to prevent multiple enumeration (i.e. multiple database access). From what I read, I should not modify the DAL to fit customer need. Instead, customer should handle the returned `IEnumerable` properly. So my questions are:

- in this situation, can the customer force the immediate execution (if yes, how)?
- should the DAL return `.ToList()` and/or the signature be modified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're seeing is due to where you're disposing of your object context. You're calling `ToList` once you've already left the `GetItems` method which disposes of the object context that it's trying to execute against. Hence, the query executes against a disposed context, and you get your exception.

You can verify this by changing your code slightly, as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var ctx = new RRPClassesDataContext())
    {
        var foo = GetItems(ctx, i => i.SupiCode.Contains("TestCode"));

        // force execution. context is still open so query works.
        var bar = foo.ToList();
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<Item> GetItems(RRPClassesDataContext ctx, Func<Item, bool> filter)
{
    return ctx.Item.Where(filter);        
}
```

So, to answer your questions specifically:

> in this situation, can the customer force the immediate execution (if yes, how)?

No, you cannot "force" the consumer (which I think is what you mean by "customer"?) to execute a query, unless you yourself force execution of the query (by calling `ToList` or `ToArray`, etc). Note that you *can* do this without violating your API:

```
private static IEnumerable<Item> GetItems(Func<Item, bool> filter)
{
    using (var ctx = new RRPClassesDataContext())
    {
        // Forces execution and safely allows the context to be disposed.
        // Still returns an IEnumerable<Item> so the method contract
        // is preserved.
        return ctx.Item.Where(filter).ToList();
    }
}
```

This is the only way that you can ensure that the query does not get executed multiple times.

> should the DAL return .ToList() and/or the signature be modified?

It depends on your application's architecture. If your DAL is going to be responsible for opening and closing the database connection (i.e. creating/destroying the context class) then you have no choice - you *must* force execution before the context closes (to avoid the context disposed exceptions).

However, if you can guarantee your DB context stays alive after the method has finished execution (for example, if you share one context class per web request ), then no, you don't necessarily have to force execution.

One way of doing this would be to dependency inject your data context class into your DAL, something like:

```
public class ItemDAL
{
    private readonly RRPClassesDataContext _dataContext;

    public ItemDAL(RRPClassesDataContext dataContext)
    {
        _dataContext = dataContext;
    }

    public IQueryable<Item> GetItems(Func<Item, bool> filter)
    {
        return _dataContext.Items.Where(filter);
    }
}
```

The downside of this approach is (as you've hinted at) you can't guarantee that the you won't end up executing the query twice (as its now up to the caller to force execution of the query).

Answer (score 0):

Writing this  **ctx.Item.Where(filter)** linq only will create a linq to sql query,  it will be executed only when you call ToList(). 
If you enumerate through the List then query will be run against DB, since you are returning as IEnumerable to main class and ToList() is forcing the query exections its throwing the error.

Yes, you should force execute immediate execution by ToList().

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the Context reference to leak out from your DAL, you will have to execute the query inside the GetItems method and return the result. Which as you already doing via .ToList.

In My opinion, it is also the write thing to do in your case. you want the query to execute and return the results immediately, creating an instance of context is a really cheap operation, so creating it  just in time of executing query is good practice. GetItem method Signature could be changed into

```
private static ICollection<Item> GetItems(Func<Item, bool> filter)
    {
        using (var ctx = new RRPClassesDataContext())
        {
            return ctx.Item.Where(filter).ToList(); <-- this works
        }
    }
```

This will solve your "possible multiple enumeration" issue as well.